# Regular expression for validating directry path

Tags: php, regex

I have already tried with the following regular expression but it is not working as I expected (xampp php)

```
$slug = "test123/abc_xyz-001" //this is valid

$reg = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-/]+$/';

if (preg_match($reg, $slug)) { // the slug shoul only contain the combination of alpha numeric and _ - /
    //It is a valid path
}
else{
    //not valid 
}
```

**valid case**

abc

123

abc12d3

abc_123s

abc-xyz

test123/abc_xyz-001

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: xampp in windows

Comment: $reg = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-\/]+$/'; this is not working

Comment: [`$reg = '~^[a-zA-Z0-9_/-]+$~'`](https://regex101.com/r/5ncoSA/1).

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew it is working